A guy dreams of falling into the ocean from his couch
Can anyone identify a movie with these two scenes?

A guy is sleeping and he dreams that fell into the ocean... from his couch
A man approaches the main character claiming he stole his ideas from his book.
main claims that his book was published before the other book


Scene two sounds like it could be from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_window

Ahhh yes thank you so much!

Andrea - its great you have an answer.  The way that StackExchange works is that you can 'accept' the correct answer below by clicking on the checkmark.  That way Jim will get rewarded for his answer.

Scene two sounds like it could be from Secret Window.
